# How to start an Intent with data types other than strings or ints?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an app that I control the Sphero with via the Sphero Android SDK and in my MainActivity, I have the user connect the Sphero and that Sphero is hooked to the variable mRobot. I want to create an Intent which I already have in my MainActivity:

```
Intent calibrationIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalibrationActivity.class);
calibrationIntent.putExtra("Robot", mRobot);   
startActivity(calibrationIntent);
```

Here, I put the mRobot variable in the `putExtra()` in the `CalibrationActivity.class`, I tried to get the extra variables, but I couldn't:

```
Intent calibrationIntent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
Sphero mRobot = bundle.getString("Robot");
```

I get an error in the line`Sphero mRobot = bundle.getString("Robot");` because I am trying to convert a Robot data type into a string.

How would I go about passing the `mRobot` variable through intents so I could modify it in the other activity? I tried to convert to a string in my MainActivity using `mRobot.toString();`, but I don't know how to convert it back into a `robot` in the `calibrationActivity`.

EDIT:

I tried using `getParcelable()` and `getSerializable()` in my `MainActivity` and in my `CalibrationActivity`, I cast the string into a Sphero via

```
Sphero mRobot = (Sphero) bundle.getParcelable("Robot");
```

or

```
Sphero mRobot = (Sphero) bundle.getSerializable("Robot");
```

But as soon as I press the button after the Sphero is connected, the app crashes, and the log is `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: orbotix.robot.base.Robot cannot be cast to orbotix.sphero.Sphero`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I guess I didn't read your problem carefully enough.

> I get an error in the line `Sphero mRobot = bundle.getString("Robot");` because I am trying to convert a Robot data type into a string.

I didn't catch that you said it was a `Robot` data type, I just looked at your declaration of `mRobot` as a `Sphero`. Now look at your error message:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: orbotix.robot.base.Robot cannot be cast to orbotix.sphero.Sphero

The problem is that `mRobot` is not a `Sphero`.  It is a `Robot`. Specifically, it is a `orbotix.robot.base.Robot`.

Change to this:

`Robot mRobot = (Robot) bundle.getParcelable("Robot");`

assuming you have

`import orbotix.robot.base.Robot`

I'm not familiar with the type system of the Sphero SDK, so I don't know how `Sphero` and `Robot` are related in the type hierarchy, but the error message is telling you: You serialized a `Robot` and are trying to deserialize it into a `Sphero`.

Answer (score 0):

Whether Sphero is serializable or not, you can always have a shared singleton to pass the data between activities. This won't be limited to any specific type of data. A simple implementation will be like this:

```
public class DataHolder {
  private Sphero mRobot;
  public Sphero getData() {return mRobot;}
  public void setData(String mRobot) {this.mRobot = mRobot;}

  private static final DataHolder holder = new DataHolder();
  public static DataHolder getInstance() {return holder;}
}
```

Then in your caller method, do this:

```
Intent calibrationIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalibrationActivity.class);
DataHolder.getInstance().setData(mRobot);
startActivity(calibrationIntent);
```

Then in your CalibrationActivity you can always get the mRobot object by:

```
Sphero myRobot = DataHolder.getInstance().getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast an object to a String. Sphero is an Object. You have to pass it as a parcelable extra.

```
 Sphero mRobot = (Sphero) bundle.getExtra("Robot");
```